# Symfony Query Builder : Avoid escaping double-quotes

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4

One of my database field stores Json (as text).
I'd like to query with like commande to find this text : "media":"40".

here is my query :

```
 $query=$this->createQueryBuilder('f');
 $query->andWhere("f.content like :mediajson ")
       ->setParameter('mediajson','%"media":"'.$mediaId.'"%');
```

but doctrine runs thie query (for $mediaid=40 ):

```
Select * from f WHERE f.content LIKE '%\"media\":\"40\"%';
```

And I'd like to have :

```
Select * from f WHERE f.content LIKE '%"media":"40"%';
```

Any ideas to avoid double-quote escaping ?

Best Regards

Comment: I wonder, if this is just a glitch in the debug output... you can probably tell

Comment: Right. Just tested here with the code provided. No quotes were escaped.
What's your error message or unescpected return ?

Comment: @Jakumi : you're right, it's just a glitch in the debug output... and no escape is done... My error came from somewhere else...
Thanks !